# Necessity of condition $[d,n]=0$ in the Jordan decomposition explicit counterexample

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to find an example to show that the condition $[d,n]=0$ in the Jordan decomposition is necessary. So, I'm looking for a matrix $x$ which can be written as $x = d + n$ with $d$ diagonalisable, $n$ nilpotent and yet this is not the Jordan decomposition of $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example:**
$$
D = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad N = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$

Comment: Hm... How do we know that adding these is not the Jordan decomposition of $x$?

Comment: @FireFenix777 $D + N$ is diagonalizable, so in the true Jordan decomposition we have $n = 0$.